# Reverse proxy passthrough for multiple websites

Tags: node.js, networking, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm building a website where there will be user generated content, for example under the url `website.com`. Each user might have a page (of their own content) somewhere like `website.com/user/jack`, `website.com/user/lucy`, etc. This number of users (as well as their names) are dynamic and can be added any time. I already have `website.com` working and deployed.

I'd like to be able for users who have their own domain name, e.g. `jacks-website.com`, to be able to use that domain name but *effectively* have it act and behave as `website.com/user/jack`. By this, I mean the following:

- `jacks-website.com` is has the same DNS records as `website.com`.
- `jacks-website.com` serves exactly the same content as `website.com/user/jack`. This also goes for any/all (nested) subpaths, i.e. `jacks-website.com/custom-path` -> `website.com/user/jack/custom-path`.
- A user browsing `jacks-website.com` will have *NOT* be directed to `website.com/user/jack`. To them it should feel like browsing `jacks-website.com` directly.

I've tried playing around with Node's `http-proxy` package, where I would check what `req.headers.host` is then map it to a corresponding `/user/jack` path. However, I still couldn't get it to work as it would cause `jacks-website.com` to redirect to `jacks-website.com/user/jack`.

Also note that I'm fully using SSG/SSR on my `website.com` app, so no need to worry about client-site routing or anything.

Thanks a lot.